# How to connect HDMI/DVI ports of motherboard to VGA monitor?

Tags: display, motherboard, hdmi, dvi, vga

I have LCD Monitor **ViewSonic va1716w**. It has VGA input.
I have bought new motherboard **Intel DH67GD** which has HDMI+DVI outputs.
I want to connect my motherboard video output to Viewsonic monitor.
How it is possbile? Do i require DVI to VGA or HDMI to VGA connectors?
Which option will work for me?
ViewSonin Specs : http://www1.viewsonic.com/products/va1716w.htm
Mobo Specs : http://www.intel.in/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dh67gd.html

Comment: [HDMI to VGA](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com+hdmi+to+vga), [DVI to VGA](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com+dvi+to+vga).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You'll want some kind of adapter, yes - something like [this](http://www.google.com/shopping/product/13474474659065462587?q=dvi%20to%20vga%20adapter&hl=en&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=ee70b9ef98ce5296&bpcl=38625945&biw=1920&bih=955&tch=1&ech=1&psi=LDKrUIu8OdPK0AXr5ICACA.1353396797730.3&sa=X&ei=MTKrUMKbNYa10QXW4ICwDA&ved=0CIABEPMCMAA) for DVI to VGA, perhaps, or something like [this](http://www.google.com/shopping/product/1811306177881602036?q=hdmi%20to%20vga%20adapter&hl=en&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=ee70b9ef98ce5296&bpcl=38625945&biw=1920&bih=955&tch=1&ech=1&psi=_jGrUPKGGIHL0QXksoGIAw.1353396764269.5&sa=X&ei=FDKrUMbLEcaq0QXRhIHACQ&ved=0CHwQ8wIwAA) for HDMI. They're not particularly expensive and will do the job just fine.

Comment: I tried to use HDMI to VGA but it does not work for me. If i connect DVI to VGA, then i need to update anything like drivers or require converter ??

Comment: My monitor has D-SUB input.Will DVI to VGA work for it??